# Print single value from object in php

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have MYSQL table for the setting in my script , and i fetch this table in php object , i know how to print the full object by using while() , but i want to print a single value by using key .

This is MYSQL table :

```
    setting_name    setting_value
    site_name   Blue Box
    site_email  abdullah@gmail.com
    template_dir    defualt
    language_dir    english
    date_format d.m.y
    time_format h:m
    site_logo   logo.png
```

and this is how i'm fetching the table in object :

```
    $query_set = "SELECT * FROM setting";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query_set)
    or die ("Error in query: $query_set. " . mysql_error());
    $row_set = mysql_fetch_object($result_set);
```

i can print whole table by this code:

```
    while($row_set = mysql_fetch_object($result_set))
    {
    echo "<br />";
    echo $row_set->setting_name;
    echo "      ";
    echo $row_set->setting_value;
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

but i need to print single value from the table by using key .

note : i know that i can filter from my query , but i want to select all my table to print group of values in different locations in the same page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just one value, then you could change your SQL query. Something like,

```
$query_set = "SELECT * FROM setting WHERE setting_name='site_name'";
```

If you have to use more than one values, you can try this

```
$data = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    $data[$result["setting_name"]] = $result["setting_value"];
}
//Now you will be able to use it like this.
echo $data["site_name"];
```

Doing it with objects,

```
$data = stdClass();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($resource)) {
    $data->$result->setting_name = $result->setting_value;
}
// For using it.
echo $data->site_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this query, but googling is so hard nowadays. Don't forget to filter your input etc.

```
SELECT s.setting_name, s.setting_value
FROM   settings s
WHERE  s.setting_name IN ('my_key', 'my_other_setting', 'some_other_setting')
```

If you want only the value, remove "s.setting_name, "

Comment: Yes i know that but i need to print more than one value in the same page ... and i don't like to do more than one query .

Comment: As opposing to the chosen answer, you only fetch the results from this query that you actually requested.